# WPF Binding Listview to a ObservableCollection

Tags: wpf, vb.net, observablecollection

I'm trying to figure out what I need to change to bind this code to a listview.

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Tracks" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="20" />
            <RowDefinition Height="26" />
            <RowDefinition Height="265*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Menu Name="Menu1" />
        <Frame Grid.Row="2" Name="Frame1" Source="PageSearchResults.xaml" />
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="1">
        <Button Name="AddSite">+</Button>
        <ListView Name="ListView1" MouseDoubleClick="ListViewItem_MouseDoubleClick">
            <ListView.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemsPanel>
            <ListView.ContextMenu>
                <ContextMenu>
                    <MenuItem Name="mnuDelete" Header="Delete" />
                </ContextMenu>
            </ListView.ContextMenu>
        </ListView>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

VB:

```
Class MainWindow 
    Dim bookmarks As New ArrayList

    Private Sub mnuDelete_click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles mnuDelete.Click
        If Not ListView1.SelectedValue Is Nothing Then
            bookmarks.RemoveAt(ListView1.SelectedValue)
        End If
        ListView1.Items.RemoveAt(ListView1.SelectedIndex)
    End Sub

    Private Sub AddSite_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs) Handles AddSite.Click
        Dim i As Integer = 0
        Dim itmX As Integer
        Dim itm As New ListViewItem
        i = bookmarks.Add(Frame1.Content)
        itmX = ListView1.Items.Add(New DictionaryEntry(i, Frame1.Content.title))
        ListView1.DisplayMemberPath = "Value"
        ListView1.SelectedValuePath = "Key"
    End Sub

    Private Sub ListViewItem_MouseDoubleClick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs)
        If Not ListView1.SelectedValue Is Nothing Then
            Frame1.Content = bookmarks(ListView1.SelectedValue)
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

The main point is that I want the listbox items to go sideways, sorta like an icon view, or more specifically the Favorites bookmark bar in IE or Firefox. I need to learn how to use binding, and this seems like a good place to start.

Here's the changes that store the pages into the new ObservableCollection:

```
Class MainWindow 
    Dim bookmarks As New System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection(Of Bookmarks)

    Private Sub mnuDelete_click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles mnuDelete.Click
        If Not ListView1.SelectedValue Is Nothing Then
            bookmarks.RemoveAt(ListView1.SelectedValue)
        End If
        ListView1.Items.RemoveAt(ListView1.SelectedIndex)
    End Sub

    Private Sub AddSite_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs) Handles AddSite.Click
        Dim i As Integer = 0
        bookmarks.Add(New Bookmarks(i, Frame1.Content.Title, Frame1.Content))
    End Sub

    Private Sub ListViewItem_MouseDoubleClick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs)
        If Not ListView1.SelectedValue Is Nothing Then
            Frame1.Content = bookmarks(ListView1.SelectedValue)
        Else
            Frame1.Navigate(New PageCustomerHome())
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub mnuAdvancedSearch_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs)
        Frame1.Navigate(New PageAdvancedSearch())
    End Sub

    Private Sub Window_Loaded(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs) Handles MyBase.Loaded
        ListView1.ItemsSource = bookmarks
    End Sub
End Class
```

And the bookmarks class

```
Public Class Bookmarks
    Public Sub New(ByVal key As Integer, ByVal title As String, ByVal page As Page)
        Me._key = key
        Me._title = title
        Me._page = page
    End Sub

    Public Property Key() As Integer
        Get
            Return Me._key
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Integer)
            Me._key = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property Title() As String
        Get
            Return Me._title
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            Me._title = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property Page() As Page
        Get
            Return Me._page
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Page)
            Me._page = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Private _key As Integer
    Private _title As String
    Private _page As Page
End Class
```

Now I'm just not sure what I need to do to change my XAML to Bind to my data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solution ended up being to set an ItemTemplate and doing the binding there:

```
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
       <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" Margin="3,0,3,0" />
    </DataTemplate>
</ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can start with something like

```
<ListView.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
             <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" />
        </StackPanel>
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
</ListView.ItemsPanel>
```

Comment: I really doesn't like having anything inside of that StackPanel. As soon as I paste that TextBlock in I end up with an Unhandled `System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException:
Add value to collection of type 'System.Windows.Controls.UIElementCollection' threw an exception.` and `System.InvalidOperationException:
Cannot explicitly modify Children collection of Panel used as ItemsPanel for ItemsControl. ItemsControl generates child elements for Panel.`